# Why my processing web game works only in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processing-ide

This is my game: https://github.com/andrea96/savethequeen

Here an online version: http://andreaciceri.altervista.org/savethequeen/

I don't understand why it works only in Chrome(and I need to reload the page twice). Playing it using Processing IDE it works perfectly.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Chrome debugger says nothing. Firefox debugger says:
[10:41:28.459] uncaught exception: Error using image in background(): PImage not loaded.

Comment: Are you using the preload directive for the PImage? http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/

Comment: No, I added it now. Thank you, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the preload directive for the PImage [processingjs.org/reference/preload](http://processingjs.org/reference/preload/)